# Javascript: Invalid Unicode escape sequence while storing accessing unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode

I am setting `Fontawesome` Icon codes in `SELECT` box and accessing on `change` event. On accessing I am getting error:

```
Invalid Unicode escape sequence
```

Code given below:

**HTML**

```
<select name="faicons" id="faicons" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="uF26E" class="fa fa-500px"> 500px</option>
    <option value="uF26E" class="fa fa-linkedin"> LinkedIn</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function renderIcon(code) {
    var context = null;
    code = "F26E"
    var icon_code = "\u"+code;
    context = main_canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font='32px FontAwesome';
    context.fillText(icon_code,20,75);
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", 140, 90);
}
```

Comment: `\u` in itself is not a valid Unicode. And it's a *notation*, not a *function*. Just like `"\"+"t"` will not print a Tab.

Comment: At best you're looking for `JSON.parse('"\\u'+code.toString(16).pad(4)+'"')`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unicode escape sequences are only recognized if they're fully contained in a single string literal. Concatenating parts of an escape sequence won't work. To create a character string from a code point dynamically, try [String.fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint). This function takes the code point as a number, not a string though.

```js
// works
console.log("\u0041");

// doesn't work
try {
  eval('console.log("\\u" + "0041");');
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

// works, but takes a number
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(0x0041));

// works, but not recommended
console.log(eval("'\\u" + "0041" + "'"));

// works with a string
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(parseInt("0041", 16)));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, OK I try `eval`.. what do you recommend for dynamic unicode setting in variable?

Comment: If you have the code point in a hex string, try `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(code, 16))` (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem while add path in js file, then I added one more slash it working fine.

**Error:**

```
${dirname}\config\user_config
```

**Solution:**

```
${dirname}\\config\\user_config
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while reading a file on windows using backslash received this error.

```
con.all("select * from read_parquet('D:\sample\userdata1.parquet') ", function(err, res) {
                                              ^^^^^^
```

**SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence**

Here `\u` is throwing off JS runtime since it has a special meaning (unicode escape sequence).

I was able to escape the `\u` by using slash(/) instead. Even double backslash will work(\\).

**Both solutions below work fine**

```
con.all("select * from read_parquet('D:\sample/userdata1.parquet') ", function(err, res) {
```

OR

```
con.all("select * from read_parquet('D:\sample\\userdata1.parquet') ", function(err, res) {
```