# Invalid Unicode escape sequence

Tags: reactjs, windows, mocha.js

I have a React project that originally was developed on a Ubuntu OS, but right now we are trying to continue the development on windows.
The problem is in our unit test, we are using mocha.
We have a test that are testing that the icons are properly render, but when Mocha try to load the files it failed with:

```
module.exports = "C:\workspace\project\img\upload-icon.svg"
                                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)

...
```

And the unit test simply not run anything.

We use the icon in this way:

```
import uploadIcon from '../img/upload-icon.svg';
```

I think this is related to the back and forward slashes, but I don't know how to fix this issue.
Any help will be thankful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Invalid Unicode escape sequence while storing accessing unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305351/javascript-invalid-unicode-escape-sequence-while-storing-accessing-unicode)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
"C:\\workspace\\project\\img\\upload-icon.svg"
```

Comment: The first thing is if I do that, in Ubuntu will fail. the second thing is: I tried that but I got the same issue